# How to make two nested Bootstrap rows together fill their parent column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a layout with nested rows. My problem is that if I let the first of the nested rows determine its height automatically (from its contents), then I can't reliably set the height of the second one. My hope was that setting the second one to `height:100%` would take into account the first row div, but it does not, and instead overflows the container.

In my example below, the div with `class="orange"` is the first one, and the div with `class="blue"` is the culprit that overflows the container.

Although I could set each of the nested rows to be a percentage of the parent, and thus have that work, I am hoping there is a better solution within bootstrap that solves this. The reason I don't want to is I want a header, and to have the first row be the size of that header.

Here is a sample layout of what I am attempting:

```css
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="main">
    <div class="container-fluid full-height">
        <div class="row full-height">
            <div class="col-xs-3 green full-height">
                Words!
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 full-height">
                <div class="row orange"> Words! </div>
                <div class="row blue full-height"> Other words!</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy554usz/1)

Comment: Thanks @haxxxton for making it an in-line snippet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should nest the orange row in the blue row, like this:

```css
.blue {background-color: blue;}
.orange {background-color: orange;}
.green {background-color: green;}
.full-height {height: 100%;}
#main {height: 200px; width: 100%; background-color: gray;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="main">
    <div class="container-fluid full-height">
        <div class="row full-height">
            <div class="col-xs-3 green full-height">
                Words!
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 full-height">
                <div class="row blue full-height">
                     <div class="col-xs-12">
                         <div class="row orange">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">Words!</div>
                         </div>
                         Other words!
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/759v0hyL/2/

Comment: Thanks! Simple enough fix!

Comment: so clear guide, it fix my issue as well, (bootstrap 3)